# Same charset html and sql but errors

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

in this example I'm working with html, php and sql. There is an SQL table with a field that is "utf8_unicode_ci". I want to put this field wich contains html code and italian text, but could be chinese or russian into an html page that is displayed by browsers.

Into the html page there is this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The problem is that the text is displayed with some strange  charachters, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set utf-8 on mysql connection? After connecting, execute this query: `set names 'utf8'`

Comment: It is `utf8` (aka `utf8mb3`) for MySQL, not `utf-8`. But, indeed, do not consider server side charsets but client ones.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't working. There is no utf-8 in phpmyadmin but only "utf8_unicode_ci" and "utf8-general_mysql500_ci" and a lot of other charsets...but not simply utf-8

Comment: We aren't talking about the table collation, we're talking about the connection charset—you won't see that in phpmyadmin as it depends on your scripts. How you set it depends on your connector; if you are using `mysql` then do `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` in preference to `SET NAMES`.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique a configuração do conexão no arquivo app/config/database.php

```
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '12345',
        'database' => 'myDb',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
  );
```

Also check the configuration of the table and field that can be configured with another charset